# Is it possible to iterate over a linked list from a const method

Tags: c++, linked-list, unique-ptr, const-correctness

For reasons I won't go into, I've created a rudimentary linked list that looks something like so:

```
class Linked
{
    ...
    std::unique_ptr<Linked> next;
    std::string data;
}
```

And I want to implement a const method that will iterate over the list, thusly:

```
std::string Linked::getAllData() const
{
    std::string allData = data;
    const std::string delimiter = " : ";

    for( std::unique_ptr<Linked> &i = next; i != nullptr; i = i->next )
        allData += delimiter + i->data;

    return allData;
}
```

Seems simple enough. But so far I haven't gotten past my compiler's complaint about constness. I guess my question is slightly more fundamental. I don't want to modify each element as I iterate, but I don't want const objects either. Were these old-school c pointers, then it would be a simple matter of using a `const Linked *` instead of `const Linked * const`, because pointers were considered with this idea in mind (being variables that they themselves may not be reassigned vs. being variables the point to const data). It seems that std::unique_ptr (being a normal class) doesn't quite share that concept.

Is the only way around this really to write my one const_iterator? That seems a bit ugly to me and a lot of cruft for an otherwise really simple class and really simple method. What's the best way to simply iterate over a const linked list?

Comment: Use a regular `const Linked*`. Nothing about traversing a linked-list requires ownership.

Answer (score 4):

You should not be using `unique_ptr` in the traversal function. `unique_ptr` represents the concept of a reference to an object and an associated ownership of that object. This is not correct for a traversal method, which should only involve a reference to the object, while the ownership stays with the Linked list itself (rather than being transferred into local variables in the `getAllData` function).

Simply get the `Linked const*` from the `unique_ptr` with `unique_ptr::get()`, and proceed from there:

```
std::string Linked::getAllData() const
{
    std::string allData = data; //Initialise 'allData' with 'data' and
                                //eliminate the unused 'message' variable.
                                //(I'm guessing this was just a typo in
                                // your question)
    const std::string delimiter = " : ";

    //Use 'Linked*' rather than 'unique_ptr', since there is should be no
    //ownership management involved in traversing the list.
    for (Linked const *i = next.get(); i != nullptr; i = i->next.get()) {
        allData += delimiter + i->data;
    }

    return allData;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have other problems to fix first, before dealing with the const-ness issue. Your fundamental understanding of how pointers and references work is somewhat off the mark. Even if there was no `const` issue here, your for loop is completely broken in at least two different ways:

```
for( std::unique_ptr<Linked> &i = next; i != nullptr; i = i->next )
```

For starters, you cannot compare a reference to a `nullptr`. Ignoring the const-ness issue: `i` is declared as a reference, so `i != nullptr` is not going to work, `const` or not. Only pointers can be compared to a `nullptr`, and `i` is not a pointer. It's a reference.

Then we get to: `i=i->next;` Since `i` is a reference, this will ***overwrite*** the object `i` references with the new value. This is clearly not your intention: to clobber the `next` pointer in your class with whatever `next->next` is.

You simply don't need references here, in the first place. A simple pointer will do, and the only thing you apparently need to do here is to use a plain, garden-variety, pointer:

```
for( Linked *i = next.get(); i != nullptr; i = i->next.get() )
```

And this completely drops the `const` issue off the radar screen. It is no longer a factor, at all.

Furthermore, I also strongly suspect that you intend to begin your iteration with `this`, probably:

```
for( Linked *i = this; i != nullptr; i = i->next.get() )
```

Comment: Your understanding unique_ptr is somewhat off the mark. std::unique_ptr<> is a smart pointer object that itself has a comparison operator to nullptr_t http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator_cmp. While it is true that a reference can never be null, the object it references can. The point of using a reference is in fact to not take ownership of the unique_ptr. Furthermore, this particular loop has an exceptional case in either the first or the last, because of the use of the delimiter. In fact, initializing the string before entering the loop was precisely my intention.

Comment: You can compare a unique_ptr to nullptr and hence a reference to unique_ptr too. Also, i = i->next does not overwrite anything since unique_ptr::operator=(..) is a deleted function. It does not compile.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, here's an ugly answer. To be clear, the whole reason I don't want to use raw pointers to iterate is the same reason I didn't want to raw pointers to begin with: they're begging for memory leaks etc. I did get a little inspiration by reading about references, which cannot be rebound (the way a pointer can) http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization

> A reference to T can be initialized with an object of type T, a function of type T, or an object implicitly convertible to T. Once initialized, a reference cannot be changed to refer to another object.

Realizing that, another thought came to mind which allows me to bind a reference (without transfering ownership, as references are wont to do), maintain const correctness, and prevent using old-style raw pointers. But it involves tail recursion. I guess this is a situation of not prematurely optimizing?

```
void appendDataRecursively(std::string &data, const std::unique_ptr<Linked> &node)
{
    static const std::string delimiter = " : ";
    if(node == nullptr) return;//yes, I can compare it to nullptr

    data += delimiter + node->data;
    appendDataRecursively(data, node->next);
}

std::string Linked::getAllData() const
{
    std::string allData = data;//make a local copy so the copy can be modified
    appendDataRecursively(data, next);//append each element in the list
    return allData;//Tada!
}
```

Comment: Using raw pointers is not at all the same as begging for memory leaks. Maybe you refer to the use of the new operator. But, int* i = &vec[0] or auto* i = smart_ptr.get() has nothing to do with memory leaks. Don't think raw pointers are bad.

Comment: Yes, this was a younger more naive version of me. I can see now that raw pointers are valid if they are not trying to take ownership. In this case it's a method referencing memory owned by the same object so it should be safe. There's no risk of somebody handing me an unsafe pointer. Still, I do feel a little gross about invoking get() on a smart pointer, and then treating the dumb pointer the same way I would have the smart pointer. I do think the recursive approach here is at least a solution that uses reference semantics nicely.